# R - Averaging specific matrix indices over matrix

Tags: r, matrix, average

I have two matrices. The first, `m1`, is 100x100 and contains numbers with decimal places and the other, `m2`, is 300x100 and is sparsely populated with integers, like so:

```
m1 <- matrix(rexp(1000, rate = .1), ncol = 100)
m2 <- matrix(sample(c(rep(0, 1000), rep(1, 10), rep(2, 1)), 300 * 100, replace = T), 300, 100)
```

Each row in `m1` corresponds to the column of the same number in `m2`. Each column `m2` represents the number of occurrences of the corresponding row in `m1` for that observation.

For each row in `m2`, I want to get the `colMeans` of each row of `m1` corresponding to how many times it appears in that row of `m2`. The result should be a 300x100 matrix. I want to know the most efficient way of doing this.

It's a complex operation but hopefully you understand what I mean. If you need any clarification I can give it. If it helps, what I'm trying to do is to get a document features matrix from a word feature matrix and a document-term matrix.

Comment: you should post a reproducible example with very small dimensions, like 3x3 and 4x3, and the expected output

Comment: A general strategy would be to expand m1 into a 3d tensor (e.g., `tf.tile` in tensor flow) and then use a tensor dot product making sure to collapse the correct dimensions, followed by a `tf.reduce_mean` along the correct axis.

Comment: I don't understand the operation. I'm not familiar with a "corresponding" mean - do you mean a weighted mean? I agree with Moody that a worked example with low dimensions, 3x3 and 4x3, would make this nice and clear while providing a good test case for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dtm <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), ncol = 4)
wvm <- matrix(c(27.305102,  9.095906, 3.792833, 17.561222, 32.06434, 4.719152, 8.367996, 0.0568822), ncol = 2)

dtm
wvm

t(apply(dtm, 1, function(dtm_row) {
  vs <- wvm[dtm_row > 0, ] * dtm_row[dtm_row > 0]
  if (is.matrix(vs)) { colMeans(vs) } else vs
}))
```

Solved my own problem. But if anyone wants to improve my method I'll mark there answer as the correct one.